# How $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 - \bar X^2 = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar X)^2}{n}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics, summation

How

$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 - \bar X^2 = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar X)^2}{n}$

i have tried to do that by the following procedure:

$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 - \bar X^2$

=$\frac{1}{n}(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 - n\bar X^2)$

=$\frac{1}{n}(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 - \sum_{i=1}^n\bar X^2)$

=$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i^2 - \bar X^2)$

Then i have stumbled.

Comment: @zyx Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expand the square and use that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^nX_k=n\bar{X}$:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n(X_k-\bar{X})^2
&=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n(X_k^2-2X_k\bar{X}+\bar{X}^2)\\
&=\frac1n\left(\sum_{k=1}^nX_k^2-2n\bar{X}\bar{X}+n\bar{X}^2\right)\\
&=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nX_k^2-\bar{X}^2\\
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 5):

I think it is cleaner to expand the right-hand side. We have
$$(X_i-\bar{X})^2=X_i^2-2X_i\bar{X}+(\bar{X})^2.$$
Sum over all $i$, noting that $2\sum X_i\bar{X}=2n\bar{X}\bar{X}=2n(\bar{X})^2$ and $\sum (\bar{X})^2=n(\bar{X})^2$.

There is some cancellation. Now divide by $n$ and we get the left-hand side.

Comment: Upon posting my answer, I saw yours. I will remove mine if you feel it conflicts.

Comment: It certainly does not conflict, the style is a little different, OP might prefer it.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\bar X)^2 & = \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i^2-2X_i\bar X + (\bar X)^2) \\[10pt]
& = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i^2)\right) - \left( \sum_{i=1}^n 2X_i \bar X \right) + \left(\sum_{i=1}^n ((\bar X)^2) \right).
\end{align}

In the second term, the factor $2\bar X$ does not change as $i$ goes from $1$ to $n$, so it can be pulled out, getting
$$
2\bar X\sum_{i=1}^n X_i.
$$
Then we can say that $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n X_i = n\bar X$.  The second term is then $2n(\bar X)^2$.

In the third term, the sum is $(\bar X)^2 +\cdots+(\bar X)^2$.  This is just $n(\bar X)^2$.

Now we have
$$
\left(\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i^2)\right) - 2n(\bar X)^2 + n(\bar X)^2.
$$
The last two terms can be collected into one term.

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged it under statistics, note that the LHS is simply $E[X^2] - E[X]^2$, and the RHS is $E[(X-\bar{X})^2]$. Both of these are ways to write Variance of $X$, hence they are equal.

Comment: This is a good way to think about it. For added clarity, we are applying the identity $\mbox{Var}(X) = E[X^2] - (E[X])^2$ to the distribution that puts probability $\frac 1 n$ on each point in the set $\{x_1, x_2, ..., x_n\}$, i.e. we are applying the formula we know to the empirical distribution of the data. Another spot where this is a useful idea is in deriving sums of squares formulas with iterated variance.

Comment: @Calvin Lin How $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar X)^2=E(X-\mu)^2$? That is, How $\bar X=\mu$? Is that for $E(\bar X)=\mu$? kindly explain.

Comment: @tree That is the definition. $\bar{X} = E[X] = \mu$ (just different notations that people use). Note that it is $ E[ (X-\mu)^2]$, and not $\left[ E[X-\mu] \right]^2$. The formula follows by definition of expected value.

Comment: @CalvinLin Isn't $\mu=$ population mean and $\bar X =$ sample mean? if so $E(X)=\mu$,no doubt. but $E(X)=\bar X$?

Comment: Ah, my bad. I often do not distinguish between the two (because I do not care about population vs sample). Let me edit it slightly to remove talking about $\mu$.